# Xcode6: What does faded (grey) check button in Connections Inspector mean?

Tags: ios, xcode6

In the process of debugging the application I'm working on, I read some other threads here that posted with the same error message I had received and one of the recommendations was to look at the connections inspector and fix anything broken there.

So in the process of doing this, I've noticed something I don't understand.

While there are no exclamation marks in the connection inspector to warn me of broken links here, I noticed that some outlet and segue connections had a black button next to them (to show they are active) but the view outlet has a grey/faded/half-checked button, while the others are all unchecked (blank).

What does this faded, grey, status of the view outlet mean?

[image: Connections Inspector]

Comment: In hindsight, the second view is probably faded out because it is the current selected view.